# Rude interviewer?

Tags: interviewing

I had a bad interview at a company

I kept wondering what was in his mind why interviewer didn't tell me his name.
Also was it rude of him to not tell me?

Comment: We can't read someone else's mind.

Answer (score 8):

That is very strange.

Usually I know the names of the people I am going to talk to prior to an interview.  If for some reason, they did not want to give me their name they could have given me an alias and I would not have known the difference.

However, I suppose if your interviewer went through the bulk of the interview without giving a name why would you suddenly need the name at the end?  The reason I want to know names (or aliases) is because it makes conversation more friendly to refer to people by their chosen names.  So I could see the point of "Why does it matter (at this point in time)?"

Rather than think about whether the interviewer was rude or not, it is more practical to think about whether you would like to work at that company or not.  But do not think about it too much because it seems the company does not really want you.

Answer (score 4):

If the **only** thing this interviewer did was not tell you their name, consider the possibility that it was an oversight. It's quite common to spend a whole day doing interviews - over a dozen in a day. And each one starts

> Hello, I'm Name, a Title here in Department. Thanks for coming in ...

This person could have forgotten to say that first sentence by mistake. Not to be deliberately rude and drive you away.

In the moment, when the interviewer is starting and you don't have a name, you can ask

> I'm sorry, I didn't catch your name?

Or at the end,

> Oh, my apologies, I didn't write down your name. Can you tell it to me again?

After the fact like this there's nothing you can do, but if everything else about the interview was great, I wouldn't let this one detail lead you to conclude it is a horrible company. Sometimes people just slip up for a moment.

Comment: "If the only thing this interviewer did was not tell you their name, consider the possibility that it was an oversight" It's also possible that this was a deliberate interview tactic - if you don't know who the interviewer is, they could be anyone from the CEO to the janitor, and they could observe your behavior towards them.